# MKMapView addAnnotation not adding annotation immediately

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have the following simple code:

```
self.departureAnnotation = [[UserAnnotation alloc] init];
self.departureAnnotation.coordinate = self.map.centerCoordinate;
[self.map addAnnotation:self.departureAnnotation];

[self.map selectAnnotation:self.departureAnnotation animated:YES];
```

What this code should do (obviously) is to add the annotation to the map and immediately select it.

Nevertheless, this code on my not-jailbraked iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1.1 is not selecting the annotation (the callout is not showing), but this works perfectly in the iOS 6 Simulator.

In order to fix this, I've made the following, which basically delays the selection of the pin for 0.2 seconds, which I don't like:

```
self.departureAnnotation = [[UserAnnotation alloc] init];
self.departureAnnotation.coordinate = self.map.centerCoordinate;
[self.map addAnnotation:self.departureAnnotation];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(selectPin:) userInfo:self.departureAnnotation repeats:NO];

- (void)selectPin:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self.map selectAnnotation:timer.userInfo animated:YES];

}
```

Why is this happening ?

PS: Also, following the same pattern, if I check `[self.map viewForAnnotation: self.departureAnnotation]` instead of selecting the pin, the view is nil. After those 0.2 seconds delay, it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

`MKMapView` probably needs run loop cycle to be finished before it can give you the annotation view / select the annotation. If so, don't use the timer, dispatch your `selectAnnotation:animated:` to the next run loop cycle with ...

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self.map selectAnnotation:self.departureAnnotation animated:YES];
} );
```

... will probably help.

Also documentation states that you need to add annotations right away, because `MKMapView` decides which annotation is on/off screen and therefore it returns view for it or not.

Just my $0.02 ...

Comment: The solution with the `dispatch_async` didn't work. About adding the annotations right away: what if the data needed to plot the annotation comes from a server call?

Answer (score 0):

It could happen because `CATransaction`([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)). `CATransaction` "collect" all the changes that you made on CALayers between states of begin and commit. Sometimes, probably for not correct programming techniques, happen that two methods goes in "conflict", usually when they are async. For me it happened using buttons, like when you activate one button and want to deactivate the others the same time. I guess that other fix could be to call 
 `[self.map setNeedsDisplay];`right after `[self.map addAnnotation:self.departureAnnotation];` or use this piece of code after the same method:

```
id __weak weakSelf = (id)self; 
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{[weakSelf.map selectAnnotation:weakSelf.departureAnnotation animated:YES];}];
```

Comment: I can see how `[self.map setNeedsDisplay]` may make the select work, but I doubt it because of the annotationView being nil at that point. Using the `setCompletionBlock` didn't work either: the view is still `nill` at that point.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the prev post I'm updating